# SSRS Matrix hide last column

Tags: matrix, reporting-services

I want to hide the last column for matrix in SSRS.

The column is in number format.

I have try the column visibility with expression like

```
IIF(Fields!abc.Value = Last(Fields!abc.Value), true, false)
```

but it didnt work. It still show all columns.

Is it my last function use incorrectly?

Any other way to do this ?

Comment: "It didn't work" is usually not a sufficient error description for SO. If you hope for a good answer you should be more explicit.

Comment: @Einar Sundgren I have edited the questions, I means it will still show all columns without hiding the last column.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the report, showing groupings?

Comment: Have you tried substituting the actual field name instead of using Last(field) to troubleshoot?

I think this should work if you just used Last over the dataset - 

`IIF(Fields!abc.Value = Last(Fields!abc.Value, "Dataset"), True, False) `
Though if it did, all your columns should have been hidden before.

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about the last column, or do you mean the last row?